# Characters lost in Mysql migration

Tags: mysql

I have a access db which I need to migrate to MySQL, the problem is that some fields in several tables store a couple of characters that are not correctly migrated (some converted into '?') so the information is lost.

These are the caracteres (▲▼[Lucida Sans Unicode, Characters map of windows]) also (áéíóú[spanish])

Can someone give me a hand with this?

Comment: you probably just need to set the charset of your mysql database. [This might be helpful](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-database.html).

Comment: Sounds like the behavior that would be observed when characters in one characterset don't have a corresponding character in a target characterset,  [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: ... and [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: I changed the default database charset to utf8 now the migration fails all the way. After reading both articles I understand one thing I have to figure it out which encoding system is access using and then set it in the mysql database. Which lead me to a bouch of other questions, can I set at field level? table level? database level? I´m afraid I would miss-use memory, or things would work partially fine becuse of the retrocompatibility and I would fine some errors in the future.

Comment: I´ve never managed to solve the problem, when initially migrated those values are lost. But when the frontend generates those values and save the changes mysql saves and displays them correctly. So in most cases you just need to update.